# Flutter How do you navigate to another page in search function

Tags: flutter, dart, search

So,after I use `SearchDelegate` class and It have a `buildResults` Widget and I want to navigate in this Widget by using Navigator function[This is code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e4ACR.png)

```
@override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
       //I want to navigate to another page
  }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58907287/12212907

Answer (score 0):

you need to handle the state of search results separately you can use any state management tool to achieve the desired result in an easy way.

please refer to this [link](https://gist.github.com/felangel/11769ab10fbc4076076299106f48fc95)

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can navigate to another page with `Navigator.push`

```
Navigator.push(
      context,
      MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => YOURPAGE(),
      ),
    );
```

And to come back to the original page you can user `Navigator.pop(context);`

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Navigator.push. to navigate to other screen that desplay the data>
[Flutter Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html).